# Open 3rd party application in corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk, url-scheme

I am trying to open the 3rd party application in my game using url scheme in corona sdk I found some good stuff but they had explain how to handle when your application is open using URL Scheme.

I followed this link

http://coronalabs.com/blog/2011/12/22/using-app-url-schemes-in-ios/

this link contain how to handle url scheme only

Can anyone explain me how to open 3rd party application in my game or application using corona sdk.?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

Youc can only open htmls app & games or any html content you want using this

```
system.openURL( url )
```

where URL is your actual URL.
for eg.

system.openURL( [Open 3rd party application in corona sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154741/open-3rd-party-application-in-corona-sdk) )

But if you don't want this to be open in browser, you can use web view.

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/WebView/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I got the solution for it which i will share in this forum.